# change fotorama slider

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, gallery, fotorama-slider

I want to place the fotorama slider in an absolute div that is behind other elements.
Also the slider should behave like the css background property cover.

I found that the slider plugin used has an option to set to cover. But I can't find out how to set it.
Also when I change the div containing the fotorama to position absolute it just ignores the height altogether.
This might be because of that cover option as the slider will scale the image up and the image is 4:3 but the space is 16:9.

How can I change/set this behavior?

Comment: Please provide link of slider & what u have tried

Comment: I have tried to set 'data-fit="cover"' (http://fotorama.io/customize/fit/) on several elements of the slider. I just use standard luma, so that slider. No changes on the code so far.